# How can I redirect requests to a sub-directory with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, lamp

I'm running a basic test to make sure the server supports .htaccess.  Unfortunately, we're having a bit of an issue:

This is the structure of the website:

- /
- .htaccess
- /test
- /test/index.html

What I want to do is display (/test/index.html) when the user hits the root directory.

I'm using the following .htaccess script:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^$ test/$1 [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) test/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

As a result, I'm getting *Internal Server Error*.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting 500 error because $1 is undefined in first case. Change it to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^$ test/$1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*) test/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sorry, excuse my mistake - I'm a bit new to the Linux world.  That works great!  How would I go about making it work for files too?  That rule seems to just do a directory?

Comment: How exactly do you want to redirect in case of files?

Comment: For example, if I request www.domain.com/file.html, the .htaccess would rewrite to /test/file.html (but obviously for all manners of files, incl. images etc)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Put this in the 'test' directory & it should do the trick!